# Extract non-string elements in list python3

Tags: python

I have a list where each element is stored as a string

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', '100','200.6']
```

How can I extract only the numeric elements

```
[100, 200.6]
```

I cannot convert the elements using `[float(i) for i in temp]` as string elements cannot be converted to float. I need to retain the string elements as they are and just filter out the numeric elements.

Comment: You can you [`Filter`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter)

    `def is_number(s):
      try:
         float(s)
         return True
     except ValueError:
         return False

    filter(is_number, A)`

this is cleaner than adding your own for loop

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, you can use `re.match` to check if the element matches a number with decimal point and then convert it to a float

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', '100', '200.6']
>>> import re
>>> [float(e) for e in A if re.match(r'\d+\.?\d*$', e)]
[100.0, 200.6]
```

But as folks have pointed out in the comments, if you floats in unconventional formats, you have to write a utility function to convert the string to float when possible or return None and then `filter` the list

```
>>> def is_float(n):
...     try:
...         return float(n)
...     except:
...         return None
... 
>>>
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', '100', '200.6']
>>> list(filter(is_float, A))
['100', '200.6']
```

Comment: What about '1e+10' for example? Also negative numbers.

Comment: This misses a large number of strings that can be converted to floats.  By far the easiest and most robust option is attempting the cast, as shown in the duplicate.  For example, in Python `'10_000'` can be cast to float.  [This article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) comes to mind here.